# Where is Bootstrap located in the DOM

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Our website gets the Bootstrap from a CDN but this has caused issues with a few of our clients whose network security blocks the request. We've also had this happen with Syncfusion's CDN and as a temporary workaround we check for `window.ejs` and alert the user if it's not there. I'm having trouble finding anything related to Bootstrap in the DOM in order to implement the same fix.

Comment: why don't you just download Bootstrap from npm ?

Comment: Bootstrap is often bundled into other CSS and JS files. We have no idea. Look into each .js and .css file and do a string search. You may have to look for class names (`col-`, `text-`) as comments may have been stripped during bundling.

Comment: Also, any client who blocks Bootstrap's standard CDN is likely to be having problems elsewhere, as Bootstrap is ubiquitous. You might offer to provide a domain whitelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM, or Document Object Model, is different from the `window` object on which you've found `window.ejs`. While the JavaScript API can be used to access the DOM, `window` is part of the browser's JavaScript API that provides access to many aspects of the users' experience.

I think you're trying to "feature detect" the presence of Bootstrap by inspecting the JavaScript API.

**Location in the JavaScript API**

*If* Bootstrap JS is loaded (Bootstrap can be loaded with only the CSS component), then its jQuery plugins will be available in JavaScript.

To detect whether Bootstrap has been loaded on a page, try something like `var isBootstrapLoaded = typeof $().tooltip !== 'undefined'`. This checks for the presence of the [Bootstrap tooltip API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/).

**Location in the DOM**

To answer your question more literally by its title...

Bootstrap is included in a page using `<script>` and `<link>` tags for JavaScript and CSS, respectively. See the [Bootstrap homepage](https://getbootstrap.com/) for example markup.

These can be located anywhere in the page, but are usually found inside the `<head>` element.

**Dealing with blocked network requests**

One solution to blocked requests to Bootstrap is to [self-host the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39115199/684776). The performance benefit of CDNs is waning with browsers' additions of cache privacy protections. Often self-hosting is actually beneficial for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. JS isn't my strong suit so I was worried if my question would make sense. The first thing our website loads from Bootstrap is a modal so `var isBootstrapLoaded = typeof $().modal !== 'undefined'` should work for what I need.

Comment: @TLT no worries! The word DOM threw me off, but the `window.ejs` example cleared it up. Best luck!